# counting sort not working for large data set

Tags: c++

I wanted to implement counting sort for large inputs to compare time complexity. i have written following code. it works fine for small inputs as for(int size = 50; size<=500; size= size+100) but when I increase size as for(int size = 10000; size<=100000; size= size+50000) i cannot get correct output. need help thankyou.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
 using namespace std;
void counting_sort(int a[], int size)
{
int i, j, k;
int idx = 0;
int low, high;

low = high = a[0];
for(i = 1; i < size; i++) 
    {
 low = (a[i] < low) ? a[i] : low;
 high = (a[i] > high) ? a[i] : high;
}

k = high - low + 1;
int *c = new int [k]; 
for(i = 0; i < k; i++) c[i] = 0;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) c[a[i] - low]++;
for(i = low; i <= high; i++) 
    for(j = 0; j < c[i - low]; j++) a[idx++] = i;
          for (int i = 0; i < size;  i++ )
          { 
       cout << a[i] << " ";
          } delete [] c;
  }

   int main()
     {
          srand(time(0));
          int*a;
          double t1, t2;
          for(int size = 50; size<=500; size= size+100)
          {
             a= new int[size];
              for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
             {
              a[i]=rand()%10000;
             }
            t1=clock();
           counting_sort(a, size-1);
           t2=clock();
           cout << setw(10) << (t2 - t1) / CLK_TCK << "sec\n" << endl;
           delete[]a;
         }

}
```

Comment: _Another problem is that..._ - "another problem" is a reason for a separate question post, please don't lump unrelated things together. As to this other problem though, I wonder how the results would look if you initialized `t1` (perhaps with a `t1=clock();` just before the call to `counting_sort()`) instead of declaring it and never setting it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideone problem. Visual Studio works ok. Also, `counting_sort(a, size)`, not `size-1`

Comment: thanks for rply but using size or size-1 didnot make any changes.

Comment: Changing IDE will make changes. Code is ok in general. `size-1` dont make any changes, _visible to you_, but in output file they are.